# Is there anyone who has tried using 'NuScenes data set'?

Tags: python, dataset

I'm trying to execute an example, CameraRadarFusionNet.
(https://github.com/TUMFTM/CameraRadarFusionNet)

I did 'git clone' it on my Ubuntu,
and did execute the following tutorial.
I also downloaded the required dataset.

I got this error.

```
File "../crfnet/data_processing/generator/crf_main_generator.py", line 78, in create_generators
    nusc = NuScenes(version='v1.0-mini', dataroot='/data/sets/nuscenes/', verbose=True)
  File "/home/aicar/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nuscenes/nuscenes.py", line 54, in __init__
    assert osp.exists(self.table_root), 'Database version not found: {}'.format(self.table_root)
AssertionError: Database version not found: /data/sets/nuscenes/v1.0-mini
```

what is wrong?

I have
Ubuntu 18.04
python 3.6
cuda 10.0, cudnn, tensorflow-gpu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the a similar issue when I use the nuScenes dataset and here's my solution:

### 1. Download and Unpack the dataset

You need to unpack your content in the `v1.0-mini` (or `v1.0-trainval`, or `v1.0-test` if you downloaded the other two versions). You should see a similar file structure to this:

[picture of my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJmzM.png)

### 2. Change the default values of the `dataroot` and `version`:

Then, go to your `~/nuscenes-devkit/python-sdk/nuscenes/scripts/assert_download.py` file, it originally should look like this (the main portion):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

# Settings.
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test that the installed dataset is complete.',
                                 formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('--dataroot', type=str, default='/home/ss/data/sets/nuscenes',
                    help='Default nuScenes data directory.')
parser.add_argument('--version', type=str, default='v1.0-trainval',
                    help='Which version of the nuScenes dataset to evaluate on, e.g. v1.0-trainval.')
```

Change the `dataroot` to the absolute path, and change the `version` to the version of the dataset you just downloaded. For example mine looks like:

```
parser.add_argument('--dataroot', type=str, default='/home/ss/data/sets/nuscenes',
                    help='Default nuScenes data directory.')
parser.add_argument('--version', type=str, default='v1.0-mini',
                    help='Which version of the nuScenes dataset to evaluate on, e.g. v1.0-trainval.')
```

Then you are good to go!

### 3. Verify your setup

In the terminal, set the env. variable:

```
export NUSCENES="/data/sets/nuscenes"
```

Then in the directory `~/nuscenes-devkit/python-sdk/nuscenes/scripts`, run:

```
python3 assert_download.py
```

If your setup the `v1.0-mini` dataset is correct, you should be able to see a success.

Hope my answer is helpful to you.